# PayPalCheckoutSDK CapturesRefundRequest failing with Unsupported Media Type (415) error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, .net-4.8

Im using the PayPalCheckoutSDK 1.0.3 (.NET framework 4.8) to authorize, capture and refund payments on PayPal.

Authorize and capture work fine, but refund is failing with Unsupported Media Type (415) error.

Upon inspecting the request (in Fiddler) I can see the "Content Type" header is missing from the request.

Given the request is being generated by the SDK I'd have thought it would set that header if it was required! This is the code Im using which is straight out of their code example:

```
            var request = new CapturesRefundRequest(paypal_capture_id);
            var client = CreateClient();
            var response = await client.Execute(request);
```

I tried adding the following which didnt fix the issue either.

```
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Anyone know why this might be happening? Im sure im not the only one using PayPalCheckoutSDK :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

What I had omitted in my SDK request was the following line:

```
            request.RequestBody(new RefundRequest());
```

I should have been more diligent with my copy/paste of example code :D